# Member docstrings from base class parameters

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.6, docstring

I have a Python (abstract) base class that provides some methods which can be modified by base classes by setting class fields.  It's a bit hard to think of a simple example without it seeming very contrived, but it's something like this:

```
class Base():
    _name_ = 'the base class'

    def foo(self):
        print('Doing something in {}'.format(self._name_))

class Derived(Base):
    _name_ = 'a derived class'
```

I'd like the derived class's `foo` method to have a docstring that accurately describes what it does.  So ideally the base class would look something like this:

```
class Base():
    _name_ = 'the base class'

    def foo(self):
        'Do someting in {}'.format(_name_)
        print('Doing something in {}'.format(self._name_))
```

This doesn't work, of course; but can someone suggest a way of achieving this?

---

If you're interested in the context, this is a Flask application where a base class provides view methods (`get`, `put`, `post` etc) which operate on an ORM class which specified in the derived class.  API documentation is then automatically collected from the docstrings and presented as swagger JSON.  So unless I can get something sensible into the docstrings, these methods won't have useful swagger docs.

I can find plenty of people who are trying to do the opposite - override the base class's methods but inherit the docstring - but not that are trying to inherit the methods but override the docstring.

Comment: What you want to override aren't Python docstrings, they're just `class` attributes — and the way you're doing it looks correct.

Comment: @martineau All I can say is that it doesn't work.  I'm not sure if you've quite understood the question - overriding the class attribute does indeed work but that's not the point.  Given the second definition of the `Base` class above, I want `Derived.foo.__doc__` to be the string `"Do something in a derived class"`.

Comment: Your example code doesn't define _any_ docstrings, so class and method `__doc__` attributes won't have anything in them.

Comment: @martineau - suggest you read the question right through.  There is a second definition of the `Base` class which shows what I'm trying to do and it does indeed define a docstring (though not one that works).

Comment: No, the second definition of `Base` does not define a docstring — apparently you don't know what they are or at least don't know how they are defined. Look it up.

Comment: @martineau Look, if the answer is that it's not possible then fine.  I know that's not a valid docstring - if that worked then I wouldn't be here asking the question.

Comment: If you define a docstring properly in the base class, you should be able to "override" it in a derived class by having it define its own (in the usual manner).

Comment: But the derived class does not override the method that I want the docstring to change on.  So how would I override the docstring?

Comment: Please [edit] the code in your question show it show it not working, a [mre] — be sure to actually define some docstrings (that can be printed to prove it's not being overridden.

Comment: In case it's still not clear, here's what I'm trying to achieve:  A method defined on a base class which is inherited in derived classes but which has a docstring which depends on parameters which might be overridden in the derived classes.